# Router CLI command to change LAN IP

Tags: terminal

What are the possible router **CLI** command on changing LAN IP? I am currently setting up my load balance router with 3 ISPs. The 2 modems having the same IP. I know how to do it on GUI but I am limited access but have full access using terminal.

BTW, modem is Huawei BM622i

Comment: Questions about general computing are off-topic here but can be asked on Superuser.com.

Comment: @LucasKauffman thanks! I thought this is part of security.